# Rebobinar una playlist en C# - Visual Studio (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Mi aplicación consiste en reproducir playlists formadas por distintos vídeos. Le he añadido algunos controles para que el usuario pueda ponerla en pausa, acelerar la velocidad, rebobinar...

El problema surge con la **función Rebobinar**. Cuando pulso el botón correspondiente, se rebobina el vídeo actual en el que se encuentra la playlist, pero **no pasa al vídeo anterior** y sigue rebobinando, **sino que se queda parado al principio del vídeo** que se estaba reproduciendo.

He probado el siguiente código (dentro del caso en el que se está rebobinando el vídeo):

```
if (NoPrimerVideo && ControlVideo.currentPosition < 0.5) //Si no se encuentra en el primer vídeo de la Playlist y la posición del vídeo actual se encuentra por debajo de los 0.5 segundos
{
   ControlVideo.previous(); //Pasamos al vídeo anterior
   ControlVideo.currentPosition = Video.currentMedia.duration - 0.5; //Situamos el vídeo anterior (que ahora es el actual) en una posición igual a la duración de ese vídeo menos 0.5 segundos, es decir, al final del vídeo para seguir rebobinando a partir de ahí
}
```

Y no funciona a no ser que pulsemos los botones: Pausa, Play y Rebobinar en menos de 0.5 segundos que son los que hemos marcado en el código.

Es decir, parece que ese código sirve si pulsas el botón en esa franja de tiempo, pero la aplicación por si sola mientras se está rebobinando no la ejecuta.

¿Se os ocurre por qué puede ser o cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido solucionarlo!

Simplemente he creado una variable booleana que identifica cuando se está rebobinando el vídeo y luego un timer con un intervalo de 50ms por ejemplo. 
Entonces, cada vez que salte el timer compruebas si el vídeo se está rebobinando && no estamos en el primero vídeo de la playlist && la posición del vídeo está por debajo de 0.1 segundos (por ejemplo), si es así le mandas realizar el código que escribí en la pregunta.

Pongo el código para que la solución se más visual:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Rebobinando && NoPrimerVideo && ControlVideo.currentPosition < 0.1) 
    {
    ControlVideo.previous();
    ControlVideo.currentPosition = Video.currentMedia.duration - 0.1;
    }
}
```

No sé si será la solución más optima, pero sí que funciona, por eso os la dejo aquí por si puede ayudar a alguien.

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Con una estructura `if else` si que debería de funcionar (antés no habñia visto que tenñias el condicional ya puesto)

```
if (NoPrimerVideo && ControlVideo.currentPosition < 0.5) //Si no se encuentra en el primer vídeo de la Playlist y la posición del vídeo actual se encuentra por debajo de los 0.5 segundos
{
           ControlVideo.previous(); //Pasamos al vídeo anterior
}
else 
{
    //Situamos el vídeo anterior (que ahora es el actual) en una posición igual a la duración de ese vídeo menos 0.5 segundos, es decir, al final del vídeo para seguir rebobinando a partir de ahí
    ControlVideo.currentPosition = Video.currentMedia.duration - 0.5; 
}
```

Es posible que igual quieras hallar la diferencia de tiempo que hay entre el ultimo segmento de video antes de pasar al anterior, para así poder controlar que realmente inicias el rebobinado del video anterior justo al final del mismo. Para ello podrías controlar el número de bloques de 0.5 segundos de los que se compone el vídeo. Es decir, si el video dura 2 minutos, entonces `n_blocks=120/0.5`, por ejemplo.

Comment: No funciona con el código que me has planteado. Lo que hace de esa manera es que cada vez que pulso el botón de rebobinar, si la posición del vídeo que se está reproduciendo es mayor a los 0.5 segundos,  lo posiciona en Video.currentMedia.duration - 0.5

Comment: Respecto a lo de los bloques, creo que aporta nada a la app. Pero muchas gracias por contestar e intentar ayudarme. Si se te ocurre alguna otra cosa, es bienvenida :)